# How solve: (is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError. Select only valid columns before calling the reduction. )?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, typeerror

I am trying to fill null values in df['total_income'] column, but i am recieving the error:

```
 is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
```

The values to fill total_income are based on the age, education and income type of the users, here are the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\gabri\Downloads\credit_scoring_eng.csv')
```

```
def fill_na(age_group, education, income_type):
    for i in education:
        for j in income_type:
            for f in age_group:
                df.loc[(df['total_income'].isna()) & (df['education']==i), 'total_income']=df.loc[(df['total_income'].isna())&(df['education']==i)&(df['income_type']==j)&(df['age_group']==f)].median()
    return dff
df['total_income']=fill_na(df['age_group'], df['education'], df['income_type'])
print(df.sort_values(by='total_income', ascending=False).head(numeric_only=True))
```

I am expecting fill miss values on total income column, with median values with the paramnters of the specif classes.

Here the error message:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3088\670034715.py:9: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  df.loc[(df['total_income'].isna()) & (df['education']==i), 'dob_years']=df.loc[(df['total_income'].isna())&(df['education']==i)&(df['income_type']==j)&(df['age_group']==f)].median()
C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3088\670034715.py:9: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  df.loc[(df['total_income'].isna()) & (df['education']==i), 'dob_years']=df.loc[(df['total_income'].isna())&(df['education']==i)&(df['income_type']==j)&(df['age_group']==f)].median()
```

Infinitly reapeting.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
.median(numeric_only=True)
```

instead of

```py
median()
```

> DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated;

since `None` is the default value

Comment: @Thomas_Weller same error with the edited code ;-;